# Converting multiple columns headers into a single column with python?

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I don't even know where to start with this one. I've got a Data set where the Yield Percentages of a particular product are broken into date columns. So for instance 08/03 is one column with a few hundred percentages as the values. and the columns go on and on. 08/04 is another column. I want to break this out and put the dates in their own column and then the Yield % in its own column. I need to create a single column out of the date headers and then create another column out of the percentages. I have no code to share as I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: how is the data stored? is it in a file? if so what kind of file? is it already in memory? if so how did it get there, what code did you use?

Comment: I haven't used any code at all yet since I have no idea how to do this. Its an Excel file. Stored on my PC

Comment: Stackoverflow is for when you are having problems with code _you have already tried_ it really isnt a forum to teach you the basics of programming or a place where people are going to write your code for you. I suggest doing a basic python programming course there are plenty of them for free online.